# Java library dependencies not found in my Play2 scala application

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.1, apache-commons-net

I have a play2 scala app where I need to do some ftp operations.
Since I have previously worked with `org.apache.commons.net` I thought
why not reuse some knowledge and implement this in my play2 scala app.

I added the dependency:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
    "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.8",
    "commons-net" % "commons-net" % "3.2"
  )
```

Check the dependencie with `play dependencise`:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| Module                                                 | Required by                                            | Note                                    |
+--------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| commons-net:commons-net:3.2                            | importer:importer_2.10:1.0-SNAPSHOT                    | As commons-net-3.2.jar                  |
```

look fine.
Updated my project with `play clean compile` and then `play idea` but it still can't find the libs. 
When doing `import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;`, `.net` is not found.
I guess I have forgotten something. But what?

Comment: Are you using an IDE? In that case you'd have to re-generate the project file before your dependencies will be visible in it (IntelliJ for sure, and I think Eclipse as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm this is very strange. As stated in the question i did `play idea` to regenerate my project but that didn't work. So I deleted all idea files and did `play idea` and viola the `import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient` works like a charm!